# How can i open an application as a different user within an application opened as another user?

Tags: powershell, scripting

Scenario: I have written a WinForm Powershell GUI that launches as a user with certain elevated rights but in the GUI I have a button that opens MSedge to a url. I need it to launch MSedge as the non elevated account the user is logged into windows with. How can I make this happen. This is the current function the button is executing.

```
function MIM {
[system.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("msedge","https://mimportal.my.domain/IdentityManagement/aspx/users/AllPersons.aspx")
 }
```